# How to find my organization Id over github?

Tags: github, github-api

How I can find my GitHub organization id?

Ideally through a script or a command I can parse its output.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a better approach

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/organizations
```

(replace `OAUTH-TOKEN` by your own GitHub access token: see "[Git automation with OAuth tokens](https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/)" to get or create a PAT: a Personal Access Token)

You will see that you can below to *more than one* organization.

For each one:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN" https://api.github.com/organizations/<anorg> | jq ".id"
```

With [**`jq`** (lightweight command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), which is available [for all OS](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) including Windows), you will get directly the id.

Comment: now you need to write "/organizations" instead of "/orgs"

Comment: @StepanSuvorov Thank you. I have edited and updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can find it with the following command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token personal-access-token" https://api.github.com/orgs/name-of-your-org
```

This command output something like this:

```
{
  "login": "your-org",
  "id": 15156947,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org",
  "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/repos",
  "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/events",
  "hooks_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/hooks",
  "issues_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/issues",
  "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/members{/member}",
  "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/your-org/public_members{/member}",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/15056937?v=3",
  "description": "",
  "name": "",
  "company": null,
  "blog": "",
  "location": "",
  "email": "",
  "public_repos": 1,
  "public_gists": 0,
  "followers": 0,
  "following": 0,
  "html_url": "https://github.com/your-org",
  "created_at": "2013-11-09T21:58:06Z",
  "updated_at": "2014-09-18T16:54:44Z",
  "type": "Organization",
  "total_private_repos": 0,
  "owned_private_repos": 0,
  "private_gists": 0,
  "disk_usage": 0,
  "collaborators": 0,
  "billing_email": "example@mail.com",
  "plan": {
    "name": "free",
    "space": 976562499,
    "private_repos": 0,
    "filled_seats": 2,
    "seats": 0
  }
}
```

So second line contain the desired org id:

```
"id": 15156947
```

Hope that help others.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`gh` CLI](https://cli.github.com/):

```bash
gh api orgs/<org-name> --jq .id
```

Note it will work out of the box for public organizations. For private ones you have to be authenticated:

```bash
gh auth login
```