# How to get count of followers through Github API?

Tags: rest, graphql, github-api

I want to get count of my followers when each time the page loads.

The endpoint I found is `api.github.com/users/tim-hub/followers`, which can get all followers data (with pagination).

### What the problems are (through restful api)

- I do not need the followers details
- Pagination is like 30 items each page, which makes it hard to count all of them

  - I am thinking about to fetch a page , i.e. page 4 `?page=4`, and do a simple calculation `30*(4-1)+[count of page 4]`, but it means it will call multiple times, because the followers are changing, if it increases or decreases, I have to call to page 5 or page 3. and loop it until find the last page.

### Why not GraphQL

GraphQL api seems like can be used to get the count, what the problem is that I want to call this through front-end, and `Graph` way requires authentication, I do not want to share my persona token to all.

Answer (score 7):

Similarely to "[How to find my organization Id over github?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672831/6309)", you can use the [GitHub user API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user) to isolate the followers number.

```bash
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://api.github.com/users/aUser | jq ".followers"
```

In my case:

```bash
curl -H "Accept: application/json" https://api.github.com/users/VonC| jq ".followers"
179
```

For a GraphQL-based solution, see "[Github API - Find number of followers for all my followers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503743/6309)".

Comment: So, this can be done only using the REST API? What about doing it using the GitHub GraphQL API?

Comment: @aabuhijleh Not sure: GraphQL was excluded from this question by the OP. I have edited the answer to reference another answer using GraphQL to count followers.

Comment: Thanks, to be clear, it turns out you can easily get them using "totalCount", followers(first:1) {
      totalCount
}, for the "first" variable you have to pass you can put any number between 1-100, it doesn't matter (this is just for GitHub rate limiting purposes)